# How to solve 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint in this example?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Please consider the following example code:

```js
interface IIssueForm {
  onDescription: (description: string) => void
}

interface IMailIssueForm extends IIssueForm {
  mail: string
}

function MailIssueForm({
  onDescription,
  mail
}: IMailIssueForm) {
  onDescription('Mail Issue\nDetails: ' + mail);

  //... irrelevant render code
}

type FUNC<T> = (props: T) => void;

function GenericIssueForm<T extends IIssueForm>(
  issueFunc: FUNC<T>,
  issueFuncProps: Omit<T, keyof IIssueForm>
) {

  function handleOnDescription(description: string) {
    console.log(description);
  }

  issueFunc({
    onDescription: handleOnDescription,
    ...issueFuncProps
  });

  //... irrelevant render code
}

GenericIssueForm(MailIssueForm, { mail: 'Test mail' });
```

Typescript error:

```
Argument of type '{ onDescription: (description: string) => void; } & Omit<T, "onDescription">' is not assignable to parameter of type 'T'.
  '{ onDescription: (description: string) => void; } & Omit<T, "onDescription">' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'IIssueForm'.
```

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJKoM4YK4QGID2UAtsgN4BQyyBIAIhBglMAA5jC0BcyAFACaNmbDt2QYwLEAHMAlMgC8APmQA3AsH4UAvhQqhIsRClQBZOMAA2mHPiKkIAD0gh%20GNDdyES5KsmIWljwSUtI6ejDYIAiiIMjmVp52JLyU1LQMTCzsnCAANH4BVjo8ZoFJ3sTyaTT0QtmxvADkCZZoWLgAOnVggRg8TcgA1P6BsgDcetQA9NMAdAvIwFBQEJYQqnDgyKuu0MgIBILhFGAAnqwoeACqAHIAwgA8ACoqCnysUASs-cjP8so1Bp%20JMKJForFkABxCAgaDABAVewvZBOFxuDwdZLEJS8PzALF4KIIHg3B4vJQFagE2xE6IABS%20Px4AHliMAwC88sgANYQM4EGCY2n2JQUapTZDgmK5ZAACy2-HWLLqWREuQE9XVYhCoDkvmo1EOIAwBHWc0sBGkmrVOVoEz8unxhOJqT86VVwjtIB4Ctcys9DVyVMNCzmNK8xMZ3wwjodflmYaWKzWGy2YB2sMEUAORwgJxhcJYiMJ9l4rSRJG5ZFGVgGz0YGaKlkG2gdQA)

There are a few questions already asked about the same problem. But I did not manage to solve or understand the problem in my example. How can I fix this?

Comment: I think `as T` would be an acceptable usage here (`} as T);`) to cast the object

Comment: @youdateme Yes casting the object solves the issue. `issueFunc({onDescription: handleOnDescription, ...issueFuncProps} as T);`
Tank you a lot, it was something I was missing.